# What are all the possible attributes on the error object when doing a catch after an $https in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, error-handling, runtime-error

Assume I have the following API call in my AngularJS code:

```
$http.get(url)
.then(function (response) {
    console.log('get',response)
})
.catch(function (errorData) {
    // Handle error here
});
```

I want to know all the possible attributes on the `errorData` object for a vanilla call failure. (eg a session disconnection).

I want to know this so I can log all the information - and improve the system from information about the failure.

My question is: **What are all the possible attributes on the error object when doing a catch after an $https in angularjs?**

Comment: do `console.log(errorData)` and you can see your complete errorData object in browser console.